# How to convert date in array format to normal date format?

Tags: php, laravel

When I take a date from database it is in the form ["1982-02-25"]. I need it in the 1982-02-25 form. What to do ?

Comment: Is it stored like `["1982-02-25"]` in the database? How do you retrieve the date? How do you output it?

Comment: Show us how you're retrieving this value in your code.

Answer (score 0):

if it's array you can convert it simply:

```
echo $date[0].'-'.$date[1].'-'.$date[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it array or string? Don't know how db can return array, unless framework model is doing string array conversion automatically.
Either way,
if it's '["1982-02-25"]' then:

```
$date = json_decode($date, 1);    
echo $date[0];
```

else

```
echo $date[0]
```